# How do I add elements dynamically to the GUI in an android app?

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface

What I want to do is create a layout of checkboxes where the number of checkboxes is decided by the user.

like if i say 5 then on the next page of my app, 5checkboxes should appear.
also, I want the text besides this checkbox to be auto filled from 1 to 5.

Or suppose I replace checkboxes with buttons, the buttons shold be created dynamically and also,in case of the buttons, the button should change color to represent that it is clicked.

how do I do this?

Thankyou!

Comment: There is a reason why i havent accepted them... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a snippet from my code. Which doeas what you are asking for.

```
// get the parent element which will hold your newly created objects
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.shouldContainer);

// create the laout parameters objects which will hold information how you would like your widget to be presented
//you can specify the same attributes as doing it "staticly" with XML file
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0);
layoutParams.weight = 1;

//create your desired object, add listneres to it, text and more
Button button = new Button(this);
//add your object, in this case button to the parent element on given position with given layout parameters
layout.addView(button, position, layoutParams);
```

Of course you have to configure the layout options according to your needs.

Comment: umm...m still a sort of noob at android programing...could u xplain some of it plz? sorry for such a stupid question :(

Comment: If you know the number of buttons/checkboxes or what ever at runtime then add this code in onCreate method. If you want to do it when user action occurs then put this code in some listener.

Comment: Oh okay! got that! thanx :)